# Angular to Node to Backend API - Multer file upload, req.file is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multipartform-data, multer

I have this setup in my application -

angular 7 --> node server --> springboot API.

There are some pages on the angular app that sends a json to the API. There are others that needs to send an uploaded image file. I'm unable to send the uploaded image to the node server and API. My code snippet is given below. In app.js, req.body and req.file are coming up as empty and undefined respectively. I looked through similar questions on the site, but couldn't get my code working. Where am I going wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

```
console.log(req.body); // form fields
console.log(req.file); // form files
```

### Angular code

module.component.html

```
<input type="file" name="file-to-upload" (change)="onFileChanged($event.target.files)">

<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <button mat-raised-button type="button (click)="onSubmitCreateTemplate()">
    Submit
  </button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
```

module.component.ts

```
export class ModuleComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  onFileChanged(files: FileList) {
      this.fileName = files.item(0);
  }

  public onSubmitCreateTemplate() {
    this.moduleService.createTemplate(
        this.receiptForm.value['merchantID'] === null ? '' : this.receiptForm.value['merchantID'],
        "some string",
        'Draft',
        this.fileName
    ).subscribe(
        ...
    );
  }
```

moduleService.ts

```
export class ModuleService {
    geHeaders() {
        const httpheaders = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
            })
        };
        return httpheaders;
    }

    createTemplate(merchantId: string, template: string, templateStatus: string, logoImageFile: File) {
        let headerInfo = this.geHeaders();
        const url = `${this.receiptTemplateUrl}`;

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file-to-upload', logoImageFile, logoImageFile.name);
        return this.http.post(url, formData, headerInfo);
    }
}
```

### Node Server

proxy-server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
var multer = require("multer")
var upload = multer();

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const appRoute = require('./server/routes/app');
app.use('/api', appRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    httpServer.listen(port);
} else {
    // for integration and production
    httpServer.listen(3000);
}
```

app.js

I don't want to save the file on disk, instead have to send it to the backend api. I tried saving on disk, just to see if the file is being saved. Unfortunately, file isn't being saved.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const { logger } = require('./../helpers/logger');
const mposLogger = logger('mppp');
var multer = require("multer")
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'uploads')
            },
            filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
            }
    });
    var upload = multer({storage: storage});
   router.route('/:serviceName/admin/receipt').post(upload.single("file-to-upload"), function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.body); // form fields
        console.log(req.file); // form files
    });

    router.all('/:serviceName/*', (req, res) => {
        ...
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

### API Backend on SpringBoot

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class TemplateController extends AbstractController  {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(path="/receipt",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public IResponse createTemplate(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> header,
                               /*@Valid AddTemplateRequest request,*/
                               @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile imageFile) throws GenericException {

  ...
  }
```

### Screenshot and Errors

[This is the form-data sent from the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HRIb.png)

On the node server end, console.log(req.file) prints 'undefined'.

Comment: Could you please add a more complete troubleshooting feedback of where you see what?   for example.  browser? is the request actually sent? which status code from server? errors?  any request coming into the server (without the file part) etc.

Comment: I think setting the content-type with all the parameters is more detrimental then it helps.   formData will already set everything correctly.

Comment: @jcuypers Thank you very much for having a look and responding. I have updated the question with a screenshot from the network tab in chrome. That is the form-data being sent to the node server. Logging req.file on the node server prints 'undefined'. I removed 'Content-Type' to let formData do the job. I now get this error when I hit that endpoint - 'Multer Error: Unexpected field'.